# How to send and receive whole text message (not just a part) using socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, recv

I'm trying to create a very simple (line) server using `SocketServer`. I'm totally new in this are and the problem is, that I don't know how to handle `recv` function. I don't want to send files or something like that. Just written text from client and response from server which could be bigger (output of ipconfig etc.)

Could you give me an advice how to make that work?

When I want to request from server something longer, for example `ipconfig /all`, it returns a fraction of the desired output to my client and waits. If do new request as a client, it returns the rest of output from previous request.

Here is the server:

```
class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    daemon_threads = True


class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while 1:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            output = process_command(data)

            response = "{}".format(output)
            self.request.sendall(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    HOST, PORT = _host, int(_port)

    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)

    print "Running on: %s:%s" % (HOST, PORT)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score -1):

In the line:

```
data = self.request.recv(1024)
```

the 1024 is a limiter for the number of bits the data string can contain, so 1024 bits == 128 bytes == 128 character string. increase the number to 4096 and you will increase the limit to 512.

Comment: I've already tried to change it to 4096 and it is not enough. I though about some loop in which I keep recieving message until is done...

Comment: Just keep multiplying by 8 until the limit is large enough. Perhaps also, add .strip() to the end of the line, or import re to remove blank lines or spaces at the beginning of lines to clean up the formatting and reduce the length of the string.

Comment: data = self.request.recv(1024).os.linesep.join([s for s in text.splitlines() if s]) Should remove blank lines from the string, if you have os imported. Hope this helps

Comment: Increasing the buffer size does not help, and the `recv` argument is not in bits.

Answer (score -1):

There are several issues.

- The `recv` is a low level function and you might receive the TCP client's input in several blocks that need to be joined together. If your "protocol" is line oriented, use `makefile` to create a file-like object and then you can read a whole line with the `readline`.
- The problem might be in the `process_command`, please show your code.
- Your loop does not handle EOF (client close).